# How to integrate $\int^a_0\int^a_0\int^a_0 \sin(\frac{n_x\pi}{a}x)\sin(\frac{n_y\pi}{a}y)\sin(\frac{n_z\pi}{a}z) dxdydz$?

Tags: integration

I am doing a physics question that requires me to integrate

$$\int^a_0\int^a_0\int^a_0\sin(\frac{n_x\pi}{a}x)\sin(\frac{n_y\pi}{a}y)\sin(\frac{n_z\pi}{a}z) \text dx\text dy\text dz,$$

where $n_x$, $n_y$, $n_z$ and $a$ are constants.

How do I go about doing this integral?

Comment: Integrate $\int^a_0sin(\frac{n_x\pi}{a}x)dx\int^a_0sin(\frac{n_y\pi}{a}y)dy\int^a_0sin(\frac{n_z\pi}{a}z) dz,$

Comment: This looks like a wavefunction in the 3D infinite potential well, are you sure the $n$s aren't integers?

Comment: Op said they are constants @DominicReiss

Comment: Right, but if it was for a physics problem, they are probably constant integers @Isham.

Comment: I see @DominicReiss.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By "Fubini's theorem" this is the same as 
$ \left(\int_0^a sin(\frac{n_x\pi}{a}x)dx\right)\left(\int_0^a sin(\frac{n_y\pi}{a}y)dy\right)\left(\int_0^a sin(\frac{n_z\pi}{a}x)dz\right)$
The integral of $sin(\frac{n_x\pi}{a}x)dx$ is $\frac{a}{n_x}cos(\frac{n_x\pi}{a}x)$  evaluated between 0 and a and the other two are the same except with $n_y$ and $n_z$.